# SQL The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound. UNION plus JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, identifier

I'm having trouble adding the field T.TEXTE_0 to the below query, I get "The multi-part identifier "T.TEXTE_0" could not be bound."

Eventually I'd like to add it to both SELECTs.
Any ideas?

```
   SELECT B.BOMSEQ_0 BOMSEQ, 
          case when B1.ITMREF_0 IS NOT NULL then NULL else B.CPNITMREF_0 end as CPNITREF, 
          case when B1.ITMREF_0 IS NOT NULL then NULL else B.YREF_0 end as YREF, 
          B.BOMTEXNUM_0, T.TEXTE_0,
          B1.BOMSEQ_0, B1.CPNITMREF_0, B1.YREF_0, B1.BOMTEXNUM_0, NULL
    FROM [BOMD]  B
    INNER JOIN [BOMD] B1
    ON B.CPNITMREF_0=B1.ITMREF_0 
     AND B.BOMALT_0=B1.BOMALT_0
    WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50' 
      and B.BOMALT_0= 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.BOMSEQ_0, B.CPNITMREF_0, B.YREF_0, B.BOMTEXNUM_0, T.TEXTE_0,
           NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM [BOMD] B
    LEFT JOIN [TEXCLOB] AS T
    ON B.BOMTEXNUM_0=T.CODE_0
    WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50'
      and B.BOMALT_0= 1
    ORDER BY BOMSEQ, BOMSEQ_0
```

Comment: And what is confusing you?  The first subquery doesn't define any alias called `T`.

Comment: You're trying to reference T.TEXTE_0 within the first SELECT statement. The alias T is not defined anywhere. Only in the second SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the first select in the union. You are selecting T.TEXTE_0 at the end of the first line, but you don't join that select to the TEXCLOB table. If you want that field to come out in both selects then you need to add the join to the first select clause as well.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to both.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use aliases across the `UNION` "boundary": the first instance in the first line uses an alias that is not defined until the second part of the `UNION`.

You would need, for example, to add this field in a `SELECT` surrounding the `UNION`-ed `SELECT`s e.g.

```
SELECT
x.*
, T.TEXTE_0
from
(
    SELECT B.BOMSEQ_0 ...
    FROM [BOMD]  B
    INNER JOIN [BOMD] B1 ON B.CPNITMREF_0=B1.ITMREF_0 
                         AND B.BOMALT_0=B1.BOMALT_0
    WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50'and B.BOMALT_0= 1
       UNION ALL
    SELECT B.BOMSEQ_0, ...
    FROM [BOMD] B
    WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50'
    and B.BOMALT_0= 1
) x
LEFT JOIN [TEXCLOB] AS T ON x.BOMTEXNUM_0=T.CODE_0
ORDER BY x.BOMSEQ, x.BOMSEQ_0
```